# How to prevent the race condition in this simple example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, race-condition, pessimistic-locking

The code below will fetch a new address from an external API if the user doesn't yet have one:

```
def create_address

  if current_user.address.blank?
    data = AddressAPI.create_address
    current_user.update!(address: data['address'])
  end

  render json: { address: current_user.address }
end
```

If two concurrent `create_address` requests come in, it's possible they'll both pass the `current_user.address.blank?` check and two addresses will be created (whatever will call `update!` last will override the other one).

How do we prevent this? Do we need to use some sort of locking mechanism?

Answer (score 4):

For example you have to use lock on `current_user`:

```
current_user.with_lock do
  if current_user.address.blank?
    data = AddressAPI.create_address
    current_user.update!(address: data['address'])
  end
end
```